# How to use expand.grid on a dataframe of characters

Tags: r

Here is what my data.frame `df` looks like:

```
df
color   shape   type
red     oval    model 1
blue    square  model 4
```

What I need is to take a combination of the different rows using `expand.grid`. Here is what I tried:

```
row1 <- df[1,]
row2 <- df[2,]
output <- expand.grid( row1, row2)
```

However, I get an error as the `row1` is not a list vector.

`head(df)` of my original dataframe:

```
       position1    position2  position3       position4       position5
1          razor   windranger  dark seer  spirit breaker   bounty hunter
2   blood seeker ember spirit       lina          techie  spirit breaker
3           luna storm spirit  dark seer          rubick  winter wayvern
4 phantom lancer storm spirit  dark seer            lina        silencer
5 phantom lancer         lina  dark seer          tuskar  winter wayvern
6     gryocopter shadow fiend     tuskar          visage     earthshaker
```

`str(df)` of my original data.frame:

```
'data.frame':   42 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ position1: Factor w/ 15 levels "antimage","blood seeker",..: 13 2 9 12 12 5 9 13 12 4 ...
 $ position2: Factor w/ 12 levels "dragon knight",..: 11 2 9 9 4 7 7 6 4 10 ...
 $ position3: Factor w/ 14 levels "bristle","brood mother",..: 4 6 4 4 4 12 12 3 12 13 ...
 $ position4: Factor w/ 20 levels "bounty hunter",..: 15 16 11 7 17 18 11 12 1 17 ...
 $ position5: Factor w/ 13 levels "ancient apparition",..: 2 10 12 9 12 6 6 4 13 11 ...`
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you could please indicate the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to provide your code... Try

```
row1 <- unlist(df[1,])
```

Otherwise `df[1,]` is a one-row dataframe.

---

I will edit this post after @firelittle replies. Here is an example:

```
> dd <- data.frame(x=factor(LETTERS[1:2]), y=factor(LETTERS[3:4]))
> dd
  x y
1 A C
2 B D
> expand.grid(unlist(dd[1,]), unlist(dd[2,]))
  Var1 Var2
1    A    B
2    C    B
3    A    D
4    C    D
```

Is it your expected output ?

Comment: the dataframe is just an example. my original dataframe is 5 columns and 100 rows. when i followed your steps the outcome gave in combinations of the other levels i had in the dataframe. Also i am new to R, i am not sure how to provide the requested code

Comment: @firelitte Please edit your post and provide the output of `head(df)` and `str(df)`.

Comment: @firelitte Thanks. Please look at my edit. I don't see any problem.

Comment: omg!! i finally realized what my true problem is. your method gave me the correct output and was never incorrect. In my output i actually wanted to map the relation once instead of twice. For example A B; and B A are the same for me and i only need 1 output. i guess it was the limitation of the expand.grid function. Thanks a lot!! i will try to find how to cut the matrix in half. would appreciate if you do know how to do that too xd.